# Excel VBA: Cut & Paste Cell Text to Above, If Cell Value to Left = 0

Tags: vba, excel

As per the title using VBA, I'm trying to cut & paste (adding commas) a text value (Column C) to the first cell above with a value (not blank), cutting only when the original cell's adjacent cell (Column B) is blank.

To demonstrate more succinctly, the following diagram (knowing the total rows is an unknown value) shows the starting point:

```
    ColumnA ColumnB ColumbC
Row1    a   b   c
Row2            d
Row3    j   k   e
Row4            f
Row5            g
Row6    l   m   h
Row7    n   o   i
```

With the following diagram being the outcome after the above:

```
    ColumnA ColumnB ColumbC
Row1    a   b   c, d
Row2            
Row3    j   k   e, f, g
Row4            
Row5            
Row6    l   m   h
Row7    n   o   i
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Generally better here if you've made an effort and hit a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through each row and move the info up if col A is empty

```
Sub test()

    Dim nonEmptyRow As Long: nonEmptyRow = 1
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim row As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("insert ur sheet name")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For row = 1 To lastRow
            If Len(CStr(Trim(.Cells(row, "A").Value))) > 0 Then
                nonEmptyRow = row
            Else
                .Cells(nonEmptyRow, "C").Value = .Cells(nonEmptyRow, "C").Value & ", " & .Cells(row, "C").Value
                .Cells(row, "C").Value = ""
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
code for reverse:

```
Sub test()

    Dim nonEmptyRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim row As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        nonEmptyRow = lastRow

        For row = lastRow To 1 Step -1
            If Len(CStr(Trim(.Cells(row, "A").Value))) > 0 Then
                nonEmptyRow = row
            Else
                .Cells(nonEmptyRow, "C").Value = .Cells(nonEmptyRow, "C").Value & ", " & .Cells(row, "C").Value
                .Cells(row, "C").Value = ""
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Just one minor question @Kubie, if I wanted to reverse the direction (Instead of the cutting the value to the above cell; paste it to the below cell instead), which variables does one modify?

Comment: @Jalkey for that you would need to change the `for loop` line to `For row = lastRow To 1`

Comment: Odd... I tried that, & the code does nothing when ran, @Kubie. Of course, reversing it continues the originally desired way.

Comment: @Jalkey are you sure? also it would be good to have `nonEmptyRow = lastRow` after the line where `lastRow` is found. Also, are you using the code on the exact same sheet?

Comment: Yes - the same sheet as above @Kubie. From `For row = 1 To lastRow` to `For row = lastRow To 1` & `nonEmptyRow = row` to `nonEmptyRow = lastRow`.

Comment: @Jalkey sorry stupid mistake, just needed `step -1` at the end of the line we set the `for loop` please see edit I maded to answer above